# Configuring Keycloak SSO on Rocket.Chat and a JSF?

Tags: jsf, single-sign-on, keycloak, rocket.chat

I am trying to configure Rocket.Chat to authenticate using Keycloak, with the hope of integrating Rocket.Chat to out custom CRM developed using JSF. I cannot use any other technology.

The challenge is right now I have failed to figure out how to configure Rocket.Chat to even authenticate with my Keycloak server. I have tried solutions here https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/issues/3897 and here https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/issues/7418 but to no avail.

What configurations are required to make this authentication work?

Under /admin/OAuth, I added Custom Aauth with the following parameters

```
enable=true,  
url=http://localhost:8580/auth,  
tokenPath=/realms/cdi/protocol/openid-connect/token,  
tokenSentVia=Header,  
identityTokenSentVia=Header,  
identityPath=/realms/cdi/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo,  
authorizePath=/realms/cdi/protocol/openid-connect/auth,  
scope=openid,  
id=rocket,  
loginStyle=redirect,  
usernameField=preferred_username
```

I also defined a realm named cdi on Keycloak, and added a couple of users to it. However, when I try to login to Rocket.Chat using these users defined in Keycloak, authentication fails with message "User not found or incorrect password". There is no event on the Rocket.Chat logs as well as the keycloak logs.

Comment: Which problems do you have with the already tried steps?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Rocket.Chat does not even call the authentication url when I try to login with a user defines on Keycloak. I have enabled logging on Rocket.Chat, but no event is showing on the logs. When Rocket.Chat starts up, it shows this

Comment: rocketchat:lib ➔ oauth_updated Accounts_OAuth_Custom-Keycloak
CustomOAuth ➔ debug Init CustomOAuth keycloak { serverURL: 'http://localhost:8580/auth',
  tokenPath: '/realms/cdi/protocol/openid-connect/token',
  identityPath: '/realms/cdi/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo',
  authorizePath: '/realms/cdi/protocol/openid-connect/auth',
  scope: 'openid',
  loginStyle: 'redirect',
  tokenSentVia: 'header',
  identityTokenSentVia: 'header',
  usernameField: 'preferred_username',
  mergeUsers: true }
CAS ➔ info Disabling CAS login service

Comment: POST your current code and add the console logs in your question, please.

Comment: Under /admin/OAuth I added a custom oauth with these settings  enable=true,  
    url=http://localhost:8580/auth,  
    tokenPath=/realms/cdi/protocol/openid-connect/token,  
    tokenSentVia=Header,  
    identityTokenSentVia=Header,  
    identityPath=/realms/cdi/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo,  
    authorizePath=/realms/cdi/protocol/openid-connect/auth,  
    scope=openid,  
    id=rocket,  
    loginStyle=redirect,  
    usernameField=preferred_username  Is there any other setting that I need to put?

Comment: Please, edit your question instead of writting everything as comments.